# PyMongo : Time delay of 2 seconds recursive

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymongo

I want to create a function in python in which, Before the record will be read from MongoDB a time of 2 seconds should be waited to and after that it executes find query, If then the record doesn’t exists yet an additional read retry after 2 more seconds should be done.
If the record does not exist either then return none.

Created a function like this :

```
def get_document(self, count):
    count += 1
    time.sleep(2)
    document = list(self.collection.find({"id": 1}))
    if document:
        return document[0]
    else:
        return None if count == 2 else self.get_document(count)
```

I think there should be a better way to do this, so What is the best pythonic way to do the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd go with:

```
def get_document(self):
    for i in range(2):
        time.sleep(2)
        document = self.collection.find_one({"id": 1})

        if document is not None:
            return document

    return None
```

You don't need a count, just use a range. You don't need `find()` if you're only after one document - use `find_one()` which simplifies needing to index lists etc.